# Is there any way to get questions by tag with excerpt?

Tags: support, api, tags, search

I'm checking how I can embed the search for one project. Basically I want something like [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).

With the search I can get the list of questions with all meta data from the search, however the excerpt is missing. Do I really need to request all questions after loading the results to get the excerpt?

(I know that I can fetch multiple questions at once that is not the matter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`/search/excerpts` method](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search#order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=android&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) supports searching by tag and returns the excerpts you're looking for:

[image]

Comment: Sorry I don't mean the tag excerpt I mean the "teaser" of the question

Comment: @rekire gotcha; I've updated my answer.

Comment: Perfect! This is what I was looking for